# Issue with the installation of terra package in R

Tags: r, package, terra

I am using RRstudio 4.2.1 and I am trying to install the terra package.
Unfortunately, I get following error that I don't understand

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘terra’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object 'my_path_here/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/terra/libs/terra.so':
  libproj.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I haven't came across this error again, so I would like some help!

P.S when I am trying installing it from the terminal, I get the following in the middle of installation :`./proj_conf_test: error while loading shared libraries: libproj.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Thanks!

Comment: The [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/terra/index.html) for terra lists `SystemRequirements: C++11, GDAL (>= 2.2.3), GEOS (>= 3.4.0), PROJ (>= 4.9.3), sqlite3`. Do you have all of those available? The "Linux" section of the installation [readme](https://github.com/rspatial/terra) suggests `sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev`